# Filter upload to audio with PHP

Tags: php, html, audio, filter

Sorry I'm quite a noob to PHP and I want to know how I can filter an upload so that it echo's out in an audio file for e.g. I want to upload an Mp4 file so that when I submit it - it echo's in an audio HTML5 tag.

I tried my version which resulted in the udio output flashing for a couple of second before fading out again.

[image]

Thank you very much and sorry if I haven't explained too well.

Comment: Can you paste the code into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])){//check if isset file
        $errors= array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];//set file name
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];//get file temp path
        $path ="files/".$file_name;//set file name with path you have to create a directory name files & have write permission if ubuntu

        if(empty($errors)==true){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$path);//move the uploaded file to destination from temp path
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!--file upload form-->
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit"/>

</form>
<?php
    if(isset($path))//check if you have path variable set
    {
?>
        <!--render audio player-->
        <audio controls>
            <source src="<?php echo $path ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
<?php
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

check this links for file upload http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

& this for HTML5 audio http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp